# Show/hide div with specified text on mouseover/mouseout of copied div

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I have a table which is copied verbatim from one div to another.  I did this so that I could have a fixed table header with a scrollable body.  The first div id is `#headdiv` and the second div class is `.bodydiv`, and the contents of `#headdiv` are duplicated into `.bodydiv` with this function:

```
$('.bodydiv').html($('#headdiv').html());
```

And then I modify the display/visibility properties of the two divs to make them look like one table.  See here for the html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/jbswetnam/KNnAd/5/

Now, what I want to do is make some help text appear when the user hovers over cells in the table. I can do this with the following functions using element id's:

```
//Copied and modified from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

function showInfo(info, display) {
  document.getElementById('infoBox').innerHTML = info; 
  document.getElementById('infoBox').style.display = display;   
}

function makeInfoCallback(info, display) {
  return function() {
     showInfo(info, display);
  };
}

function setupInfo() {
  var infoText = [
      {'id': 'header', 'info': 'Header Row'},
      {'id': 'alpha', 'info': 'Alpha'}
      ];

  for (var i = 0; i < infoText.length; i++) {
    var item = infoText[i];
     document.getElementById(item.id).onmouseover = 
        makeInfoCallback(item.info, "");
     document.getElementById(item.id).onmouseout = 
        makeInfoCallback("", "none");
  }
}
setupInfo();
```

As you can see at http://jsfiddle.net/jbswetnam/KNnAd/5/, when you hover over the table header, the text "Header Row" appears.  What I'm trying to do is make the text "Alpha" appear when you hover over the cell that says "Alpha".

I know why the function works in the header and not the body.  The header has an id which is referenced in the function above, whereas the body cells that you see are copied from `#headdiv` and therefore their id's are not valid.  But I don't know enough about Javascript to know how to fix the problem.  Using classes instead of id's doesn't work.  I have a feeling that I can refactor the whole script using `this` and perhaps calling the function out of each cell, but I just don't know how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done with this code:

```
function makeInfo() {
$('.info').hover(
    function() {
        $('#infoBox').html($(this).attr('info'));
        $('#infoBox').css('display', '');  
    },
    function() {
        $('#infoBox').css('display', 'none');
    }); 
}

makeInfo();
```

You can see the updated HTML at the same jsfiddle.